# Execute a python script using Popen with shell=False

Tags: python, shell, subprocess, popen, gnome

I would like to know if it's possible to execute this command

```
cmd = "gnome-terminal -e 'python /path/to/file.py'"

p = subprocess.Popen(cmd,shell=True)
```

but with shell=False

I tried to run this command

```
p = subprocess.Popen(["gnome-terminal","-e","python","/path/to/file.py"],shell = False)
```

but it's not working:

Thank you!

Comment: It will just open python, but it will not execute the python script (file.py) @RahulKP

Comment: Are you trying to execute python file from another python file ?

Comment: No the python script! @RahulKP

Comment: Why the downvote though?

Comment: @RahulKP: it doesn't work: read about the difference between `-e` and  `-x`  options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it is you're passing the command to `gnome-terminal`, not `python`.

```
p = subprocess.Popen(["gnome-terminal","-e","python /path/to/file.py"],shell = False)
```

Comment: Don't know why I didn't try this, but THANK YOU! :)

Comment: @Eliekhalifeh: if you want to pass separate command-line arguments as the command, use `-x` instead of `-e` in your code.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian It worked using the above answer, but thank you, I'll keep this in mind!